# Flutter Camera Plugin Doesn't save on DCIM Folder

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, android-camera, flutter-plugin

I've set Android permissions for read, write and camera on the manifest xml and I am able to take the picture and save it into the temporary folder but the app crashes when I switch the

```dart
CameraController.takePicture(dcimPath)
```

method to the DCIM(pictures) folder rather than the temporary folder. Also plugins like [album_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/album_saver) aren't working when I try to save from the temporary folder to the DCIM folder.

Using a plugin like [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) is not an option since I'm trying to build a camera app

Comment: Please tell full paths. Not only folder names.

Comment: I tried using a plugin that returns dcim path and it didn't work